# Passing arguments to Array.forEach callback function

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, higher-order-functions

```
someOperation.then(function(x) {
    things.forEach(function(thing) {
        //doing something with 'thing' that depends on variable 'x'
    });
});
```

In the code above, how can I make the variable 'x' available inside the callback function? Or do I have to go back to using a for loop in this case?

Comment: you have access to x as a closure

Comment: @Gonzalo.- ok I changed my code a bit. Will I still have access to x as a closure? because when I put a breakpoint inside the forEach callback function, I don't see 'x' in the list of closures.

Comment: to be listed on that list, you have to actual be using it as a closure. If not, all the variables of the universe of your js will be accesible. Just use it inside your function (i.e. print it with console.log) and you'll see it listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is available.

```js
let x = {
  name: 'Mike'
};
['Hello', 'Goodbye'].forEach(function(greeting) {
  document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML += greeting + ', ' + x.name + '\n';
});
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

What you're using here is known as a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and is a commonly used feature of Javascript. Basically, any function has access to any other variable in it's parent scope.

```js
function log(msg) {
  document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML += msg + '\n';
}

var global = 'global';
function firstLevel(third) {
  var first = 'first';
  
  // `global` is in the parent scope so we can access it
  log(global + ' -> ' + first);
  
  function secondLevel() {
    var second = 'second';
    
    // Same thing with `first` here
    log(global + ' -> ' + first + ' -> ' + second);
    
    // This even works with passed in arguments
    log(global + ' -> ' + first + ' -> ' + second + ' -> ' + third);
    
    // We can even change closed over variables
    first = 'fourth?';
  }
  
  secondLevel();
  log(first); // Notice that `first` changed.
}

log(global);
firstLevel('third'); // Notice how `third` is used in `secondLevel`
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: ok I changed my code a bit. Will I still have access to x as a closure?

Comment: @AyushISM Yes, you still do. I added an example which uses an argument. It works just the same. You can prove this to yourself by doing `console.log(x)` in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a "thisArg" as the second parameter to forEach so for instance:

```
let x = { a: 123 };
things = ['foo', 'bar']
things.forEach(function(thing) {
    alert( this.a + thing );
}, x);
```

Might be helpful depending on what you are trying to do.